# How to specify database name in UDF?

Tags: user-defined-functions, arangodb, aql

I wrote small UDF (based on docs page):

```
function greeting() {
    const db = require('@arangodb').db; 
    let result = db._query('for d in docs FILTER p.id == "123" return d').toArray()[0]
    return result;
}

module.exports = greeting;
```

The problem that it work only with default `_system` db. How to specify another?

I found [mention](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/data-modeling-databases-working-with.html#use-database) in docs:

> Changing the database might be disallowed in some contexts, for example server-side actions (including Foxx).

So it's impossible?! it's absurd!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending.html):

> Internally, UDFs are stored in a system collection named _aqlfunctions of the selected database. When an AQL statement refers to such a UDF, it is loaded from that collection. The UDFs will be exclusively available for queries in that particular database.

If you have a database `myDB`, then make sure to register the UDF for that database:

```
arangosh --server.database myDB ...
```

or connect to the default database and switch to the right one:

```
db._useDatabase("myDB");
aqlfunctions.register(...);
```

You cannot access different databases from within a UDF, it is restricted to the current database by design - it is an extension mechanism for AQL, which is executed in the context of a single database.